# How to publish flutter aar to artifactory

Tags: android, flutter

We have created a plugin in Flutter. Then we exported the "AAR" using "flutter build aar". Then included the AAR files to the native android app. Finally, we tried to publish the native as SDK. So that Native app users can use our flutter SDK.

When we included the local aar files created by flutter it worked fine. But after uploading the AAR to artifactory it was not working. Then we saw that the size of our SDK is only 43KB. Which means none of our flutter code got published into artifactory.

Then we uploaded the flutter plugin to artifactory manually using below code.

```
AAR(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "flutter.demo"
            artifactId "flutter_release"
            version = libraryVersion
            artifact("../../demo-flutter/build/host/outputs/repo/flutter/demo/flutter_release/$flutterSDKVersion/flutter_release-${flutterSDKVersion}.aar")
        }
```

But the app is crashing inside flutter Views.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, how did you solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When we uploaded AAR top artifactory only our code is uploaded to articatory. Means only flutter to native communication code is published as artifactory.

Then we found `.pom` file had link of libraries added by flutter plugins. So we uploaded all the AAR including plugin's AAR to our artifactory.

Hope this helps.